# org-mode: How to correctly capture email addresses?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to capture contacts (name, email address,..) with org-mode and thus setup 
the following in .emacs:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("t" "TODO in ~/org/agenda.org -> Tasks" entry (file+headline 
"~/org/agenda.org" "Tasks")
         "* TODO %?\nSCHEDULED: %^t\n%U %a")
        ("c" "Contact in ~/org/contacts.org -> Contact" entry (file+headline 
"~/org/contacts.org" "Contact")
         "* %?%(org-contacts-template-name) %^g
:PROPERTIES:
:EMAIL: %(org-contacts-template-email)
:URL:
:WORK:
:HOME:
:MOBILE:
:LOCATION:
:BIRTHDAY: 
:NOTE:
:END:")))
```

I can easily capture contacts with C-c c c, it prompts for the name, a tag, and 
the email address. However, instead of an output like

```
* My contact                         :my.tag:
  :PROPERTIES:
  :EMAIL: address@hidden
  :URL:
  :WORK:
  :HOME:
  :MOBILE:
  :LOCATION:
  :BIRTHDAY: 
  :NOTE:
  :END:
```

I obtain:

```
* My contact                         :my.tag:
  :PROPERTIES:
  :EMAIL:
  :URL:
  :WORK:
  :HOME:
  :MOBILE:
  :LOCATION:
  :BIRTHDAY: 
  :NOTE:
  :EMAIL: address@hidden
  :END:
```

So the problem is that the first :EMAIL: is ignored and instead a second 
:EMAIL: is inserted before :END:. How can I obtain the correct output (as 
described above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sexp `%(org-contacts-template-email)` will actually create a :EMAIL: property when called. If you change your capture template to:

```
"* %?%(org-contacts-template-name) %^g
%(org-contacts-template-email)
:PROPERTIES:
:URL:
:WORK:
:HOME:
:MOBILE:
:LOCATION:
:BIRTHDAY: 
:NOTE:
:END:"
```

You will get the desired output. You also don't need the `%?` unless you particularly want the cursor to be placed before the contact-name when capture is exited.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. It's working (without the newline after %^g). I guess one can't put in the :EMAIL: tag in a certain spot, it's always positioned right before :END:.